# Online vim via browser, but with copy/cut/paste to/from Windows clipboard

Tags: os-clipboard

I visited another city and forgot to bring my laptop.  A friend offered to let me use his Windows 10 account, but without installing anything (including cygwin from a non-administrator account).  It's a non-administrator account on a very locked-down machine with USB ports disabled -- not that I have a mem stick or a means of putting vim on it.

I found several online webpages offering vim functionality, either by spinning up a VM or providing a JavaScript port of vim.

- https://www.onworks.net/programs/vim-online

  - Right-click on desktop, choose to open a terminal, then type `vi`
- http://coolwanglu.github.io/vim.js/streamlinejs/vim.html

I tried "yanking" text from editted buffer (`y` command), copying to vim's idea of the system clipboard (register `*`).  Unfortunately, the text doesn't actually get copied to the system clipboard of my friend’s non-administrator acount on Windows 10.  In *Notepad.exe,* `ctrl+v` pastes content that was copied from a previous "copy" action in Windows, *not* the yanked text.

Because of the above, I will not be able to retrieve anything from an editted buffer.  **Is there an online vim editor that synchronizes the system clipboard with that of the OS on which the browser is running?**

I did not explore the above VM option of sending the buffer contents via email or upload it to the cloud.  This is because I don't want to enter login information from the VM.

Comment: Any reason you cannot download e.g. a zip file from e.g. https://github.com/vim/vim-win32-installer/releases and use that one? You just need to extract the package into your $HOME folder, no installation with admin rights required

Comment: I followed the [more information](https://github.com/vim/vim-win32-installer/releases) link to get milestone releases rather than nightly releases. Eventually, I found myself to SouceForge's [Cream for Vim](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cream/files/Vim), but got a message about this version not being for my OS. The friend thinks that it might be the locked down security kicking in. He clarified that *no* `*.exe` files should be run, so I think I'm back to looking for an online Vim. Thanks anyway!

Comment: I think Cream for Vim is no longer maintained. Also, even so they are called nightlies, it should be perfectly okay to download a zip archive from the `vim-win32-installer` github page. Those are official patch releases. You could also try to download the release 8.2, but that is already quiet old, so I would go with an up-to-date vim release

Comment: Thanks, Christian.  Unfortunately, with the additional constraint that I cannot run any (non-native) `*.exe` files, I think I am stucking using Notepad.  I will make one last stab at finding an online vim that synchronizes register `*` with the local cut/paste clipboard.